How do I add a trusted check constraint quickly
I'm adding a check constraint to a large table because I want to prepare to switch it into a partitioned table using partition switching.
The check is a simple inequality check on a column and there is an index on that column. But when I add the constraint, SQL Server still performs a scan of the whole table. Is it possible to add the constraint quickly and keep it trusted? I hoped it would be possible because of the index.
Here is a reproduction that shows that scan:
USE tempdb;
GO

SELECT * 
INTO MY_MESSAGES
FROM sys.messages;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_MY_MESSAGES ON dbo.MY_MESSAGES(message_id);

SET STATISTICS IO ON;
ALTER TABLE dbo.MY_MESSAGES
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_mymessages CHECK (message_id < 50000);
SET STATISTICS IO OFF;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.MY_MESSAGES;

This is shown in the messages tab:
Table 'MY_MESSAGES'. Scan count 1, logical reads 10955


Unfortunately, the constraint checking logic is very basic and won't take advantage of an index in the way you might hope. It won't seek for values not meeting the constraint. It could, but it doesn't.
As Dan says, a thin nonclustered index can make the scan more efficient.
Table 'MY_MESSAGES'. Scan count 1, logical reads 314, physical reads 0

You can capture the query plan with Query Store. It will show a scan, a Compute Scalar with a CASE expression to test the constraint condition, and an Assert to throw an error if necessary.


[Expr1003] = Scalar Operator(
    CASE WHEN [dbo].[MY_MESSAGES].[message_id]>=(50000) THEN (0) ELSE NULL END)

*** Output Tree: (trivial plan) ***

PhyOp_StreamCheck (Check COLUMN CNST: CK_mymessages COL: message_id) 
    PhyOp_ComputeScalar
        PhyOp_NOP
            PhyOp_Range 
                TBL: dbo.MY_MESSAGES(2) ASC  
                Bmk ( QCOL: [dbo].[MY_MESSAGES].message_id COL: Uniq1001 ) 
                IsRow: COL: IsBaseRow1000 
        AncOp_PrjList 
            AncOp_PrjEl COL: Expr1003 
                ScaOp_Intrinsic x_iopBuildSwitch
                    ScaOp_Comp x_cmpGe
                        ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [dbo].[MY_MESSAGES].message_id
                        ScaOp_Const TI(int,ML=4) XVAR(int,Not Owned,Value=50000)
    ScaOp_Identifier COL: Expr1003 


As a side note, DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS (CK_mymessages); does use a helpful index.
The internal query is:
INSERT INTO #priv_cc_temp_table18935 SELECT DISTINCT TOP 200
  'Table Name' = '[dbo].[MY_MESSAGES]',
  CASE
    WHEN NOT ( ([message_id]<(50000)) )
      THEN '[CK_mymessages]'
  END 'Constraint',
  CASE
    WHEN NOT ( ([message_id]<(50000)) )
      THEN '[message_id] = ''' + 
    REPLACE(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), [message_id], 0)),'''','''''') + ''''
  END 'RID'
FROM [dbo].[MY_MESSAGES]
WHERE
(

  NOT ([message_id]<(50000))
)
OPTION (CHECKCONSTRAINTS PLAN)

The plan features an index seek to find rows violating the constraint:

Sadly, DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS doesn't have an option to unset is_not_trusted when no violations are found.

A full scan of the table or index will be required to ensure existing values conform to the check constraint expression. You might see a slight performance improvement with a non-clustered index on message_id since fewer logical reads will be required for the validation but every row in the index will still need to be scanned.

I'm adding a check constraint to a large table because I want to
prepare to switch it into a partitioned table using partition
switching.

Consider partitioning this table similarly to the target partition table. This will ensure data in the source partition conforms to the target table partition boundaries permitting the use of SWITCH without a trusted check constraint, thus avoiding the need to validate data with a scan.

You mentioned: "A full scan of the table or index will be required to ensure existing values conform to the check constraint expression."
But that's not necessarily true, but is a consequence of Microsoft's implementation of the ALTER TABLE statement. For example, this statement is super quick:
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MY_MESSAGES WHERE NOT (message_id < 50000)) PRINT 'assertion failed'

You mentioned "Consider partitioning this table similarly to the target partition table"
Partitioning the table involves an uncomfortably long rebuild of the table and indexes which is exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid. (The table I'm dealing with is very large)

@MichaelJSwart, not sure I understand why a rebuild of the source table would needed if it's partitioned like the target table beforehand.  The check constraint is problematic so perhaps the process could be reengineered to leverage SWITCH but that's a different question.

It wouldn't. But the reason I asked this question is that the table I'm dealing with is not partitioned beforehand. And I would like it to become partitioned as quickly as possible.

@MichaelJSwart, the fastest way to partition the existing table with data is with the DROP_EXISTING index create option (e.g. CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_MY_MESSAGES ON dbo.MY_MESSAGES(message_id) WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON) ON PF_YourPartitionScheme(message_id);). This avoid the sort, leveraging the order of the existing clustered index.

I was looking for a faster strategy than that. If Microsoft could have optimized the constraint check. I would have such a strategy.

The constraint can be quickly added using "WITH NOCHECK" to ignore existing data.  You can trust the constraint to apply to new/changed data.  You won't know if the existing data complies with the check constraint.  However, you can run your own select query to validate existing data.  The PK can be used to check using batches knowing that once a range is checked it will stay valid.
ALTER TABLE TableName
WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName CHECK (Condition);


"Trusted" doesn't mean that the OP trusts it. It means SQL Server trusts it and is_not_trusted in sys.check_constraints is set to 0

Not sure why somebody would vote to delete this post.  Perhaps I'm not the only one that would miss the trusted part.
